# NVIDIA Proprietary driver not working properly

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, suspend

I have a Lenovo Z40-70 laptop which was running Ubuntu 14.04 with a HDD. After upgrading to SSD (OCZ 240GB) and installing a fresh copy of Ubuntu I came across few issues with drivers for Broadcom and Nvidia graphic card. I think now the Broadcom driver works fine, but still the Nvidia causes some problems.

I always had problems with Suspend and Resume with this driver since the SSD upgrade. Most of the time it freezes at the resumption. However I had no issues when I was running Ubuntu with HDD. To solve this I changed my Ubuntu version to 15.04. I installed quite a few drivers for nvidia, finally with the following sequence of commands I was able to solve Suspend/resume issue.

`sudo apt-get remove nvidia*`

`sudo apt-get clean`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install nvidia-current`

However even with this, additional drivers section of Software & Updates shows the driver is using X.org X server-Nouveau driver. [This image shows the working driver configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1Hx9.png) .

At this moment Suspend/resume is working fine, but I noticed some jitter in playing videos. 
Then I changed my driver in additional driver section to NVIDIA proprietary driver, version 340.96 (proprietary,tested). This caused the resume problem again. 
This time, going back to Nouveau driver didn't solve the problem.

However following above sequence of commands again I was able to successfully solve the suspend/resume issue.

How can I make the NVIDIA driver work ? Does it have to do anything with SSD upgrade ?

(Maybe this problem was there even with HDD but I didn't notice since I was using the Nouveau driver always. I didn't really care about graphics driver at that time since it looked working fine.)

Comment: These questions probably will never stop appearing.

Comment: What is worng with NVIDIA drivers ..? New to this drivers business.